# laravel multilevel relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Is it possible to make a multi level relation query with Eloquent on a deeper level than 1 level? My tables look like this :

> post_comments-> id|comment|post_id|user_id|...
>
> post_comment_replies-> id|reply|post_comment_id|user_id|...
>
> users-> id|name|....
>
> user_data-> id|avatar|...

And so I want to ask is it possible to get the **Comments** for a **Post** with all the **Replies** and the User Data for the person who replied to a comment in 1 query with Eloquent.

This is how my **Comments** Model looks like:

```
class PostComment extends Model{
public function replies(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostCommentAwnsers::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function userInfo(){
    return $this->belongsTo(UserInfo::class,'user_id','user_id');
}}
```

---

```
public function index($id){
    $posts = Post::find($id);
    $postComments = PostComment::where('post_id','=',$id)->paginate(5);

    return view('post.show',[
        'post' => $post,
        'postComments' =>$postComments
    ]);
}
```

And as I get all the user data for a **Comment** I want to get all the user data for the person who replied.
I am really sorry if this has been awnsered or documented somewhere else but I just can't seem to find the exact solution to this problem.

Comment: are you sure `user_data` needs to be in a separate table ? if it is a one to one relationship, you should merge the two tables.

Comment: Yes but it contains a lot of columns and i only use the user_data table in a few cases in this project and i don't want to call all of the user data where i only need the user id and name

Comment: you can query only the data you need using `$user = User::where('id', '=', $id)->select('firstname', 'lastname')->get()` https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/eloquent/select-specific-columns-using-eloquent-orm?page=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should look for eager loading : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

if you want to get all posts and their comments :

```
$posts = Post::with('comment')->get();
```

and if you want all posts with comments and replies of the comments :

```
$posts = Post::with('comment.reply')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with my issue.

Comment: What should I do If I want a count of reply?